# Append a String to a bolded String in VBA

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

I have a cell that contains the text  "**Collar Lot #**" and I would like to append a string onto the end of it that is not bold. An example would be "**Collar Lot #** 23456\34567\45678".  My code attempt below makes the entire string bold, resulting in "**Collar Lot # 23456\34567\45678**"

```
With Workbooks(ThisWorkbook.name).Worksheets(1)
    ...
    .Cells(7, 5).value = "Collar Lot # " & "23456\34567\45678"
End With
```

How would I make sure the "23456\34567\45678" was not bold?

Comment: This might be one good use case for the macro recorder.

Comment: Can you explain more? This needs to be kept in the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
.Cells(7, 5).Characters(Start:=14).Font.FontStyle = "Regular"
```

The Record Macro button on the Developer Tab of the Ribbon is very useful for finding out something like this.

Answer (score 5):

You would need to specify the formatting based on the position of the characters by using something like:

```
.Cells(7, 5).Characters(Start:=1, Length:=13).Font.FontStyle = "Bold"
```